I'm not receiving the Test Deliverability emails
I am trying to send an email using Apex code, but it does not seem to work. Given this, I believe it is not a code-related issue. To troubleshoot, I also tried to send deliverability test emails, which did not work either. Here are the steps I have taken so far:

Ensured deliverability settings are correctly configured to accept all emails.

Reviewed the email logs to identify any potential issues or errors.

Tested with various simple email scripts from reliable sources just to see if i receive any emails.

Sent test deliverability emails to different email addresses, including multiple Gmail accounts, but still did not receive any emails.

Tried sending emails using different codes, which all indicate success in the debug logs, yet I am not receiving any emails.

Enabled "Advanced Email Security Settings" to see if it would make any difference, but it did not resolve the issue.


No matter what code I try to implement to send an email, it is not working. I am in a bit of a rush to find a solution to this problem. Despite these efforts, I have not been able to successfully send or receive any emails. It seems that the problem is not related to the code itself.
Here are the requirements for my problem and the steps I have taken:
Create a batch class that summarizes all Opportunity Amounts for each Account.
An email should be sent to the primary contact of all Accounts, containing a table with the Closed Won, Open, and Closed Lost summarized Opportunity Amounts.
I will also leave the code below for everyone to see in case it is a code issue. However, even if it might be a code issue, why am I not receiving the test deliverability emails?
public with sharing class OppAmountForAccount implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

public List<Id> primaryContIdList = new List<Id>();
public List<Id> accountIdList = new List<Id>();

public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    String query = 'SELECT Id, AccountId, Name, Email, Is_Primary_Contact__c FROM Contact';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> contacts){
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

    for(Contact con : contacts){
        if(con.Is_Primary_Contact__c == TRUE){
            accountIdList.add(con.AccountId);
            primaryContIdList.add(con.Id);

            List<Account> accountList = [SELECT Id, Name, Open_Opps_Amount__c, Closed_Won_Opps_Amount__c, Closed_Lost_Opps_Amount__c
                                         FROM Account WHERE Id = :con.AccountId];

            for(Account acct : accountList){
                String acctName = acct.Name;
                Decimal wonAmount = acct.Closed_Won_Opps_Amount__c;
                Decimal lostAmount = acct.Closed_Lost_Opps_Amount__c;
                Decimal openAmount = acct.Open_Opps_Amount__c;

                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
                sendTo.add(con.Email);
                mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
                mail.setReplyTo('support@yourcompany.com');
                mail.setSenderDisplayName('Scheduled Apex Batch');
                mail.setSubject(acctName + ' : Opportunities Amount, based on Stage!');
                mail.setHtmlBody(
                    '<p>Below is a table of opportunities related to the account: '+ acctName +'.</p>' +
                    '<table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="1">' +
                    '<tbody>' +
                    '<tr style="height: 18px;">' +
                    '<td style="width: 30%; height: 18px; text-align: center;"><strong>Account</strong></td>' +
                    '<td style="width: 30%; height: 18px; text-align: center;"><strong>Stage</strong></td>' +
                    '<td style="width: 30%; height: 18px; text-align: center;"><strong>Amount</strong></td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                    '<tr style="height: 18px;">' +
                    '<td style="width: 30%; height: 18px;">'+ acctName +'</td>' +
                    '<td style="width: 30%; height: 18px; text-align: left;">Open</td>' +
                    '<td style="width: 30%; height: 18px;">'+ openAmount +'</td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                    '<tr style="height: 18px;">' +
                    '<td style="width: 30%; height: 18px;">'+ acctName +'</td>' +
                    '<td style="width: 30%; height: 18px; text-align: left;">Closed Won</td>' +
                    '<td style="width: 30%; height: 18px;">'+ wonAmount +'</td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                    '<tr style="height: 18px;">' +
                    '<td style="width: 30%; height: 18px;">'+ acctName +'</td>' +
                    '<td style="width: 30%; height: 18px; text-align: left;">Closed Lost</td>' +
                    '<td style="width: 30%; height: 18px;">'+ lostAmount +'</td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                    '</tbody>' +
                    '</table>'
                );
                mails.add(mail);
            }
        }
    }

    if(!mails.isEmpty()) {
        System.debug('Sending emails: ' + mails);
        Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
    }
}

public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    System.debug('Batch processing finished.');
    }
}



global class ScheduleOppAmountForAccount implements Schedulable {
global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
   OppAmountForAccount batchJob = new OppAmountForAccount();
        Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(batchJob);
     }
}

If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has suggestions on how to resolve this, your help would be greatly appreciated.

If you use the email composer on any object or the Classic email template Test & Send Email - do you receive an email? - and if not, what do the email logs say?  That is, can emails be sent from your org using OOTB email sending?  Is your org set up with email relay on?  You might be having DMARC/DKIM/SPF issues

I am not receiving emails sent using OOTB email sending. I have already tried that. My org does not have an email relay enabled. I don't think I will resolve this issue ever, let alone by Monday night. The email deliverability settings are set to allow all emails. But is the code alright for what I want to do? I don't even know where to look now, to be honest. my email log says this: Unauthenticated email from yahoo.com is not accepted due to domain's DMARC policy. Please contact the administrator of yahoo.com domain, and i used gmail aswell and same thing.

DMARC error sounds like the root of your issue.  see https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387977&type=1 and https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.emailadmin_dmarc.htm&type=5.. What domain are you sending emails from?  As for your code, you should check the Messaging.SendEmailResult[] after doing the send. Most orgs send email from a verified orgWideEmail address as otherwise the from address is the running user's address. Your code is also doing soql inside of a loop which is not best practice and can run into limits issues

Yes, apparently I need to create a domain for it to work. I'll see what I can do, and thanks for helping me. Even though I don't know why it happened only to me, other people can send through Gmail with no problem, but it is what it is.
